# VSCode how to fix typescript highlight error Argument of type {} is not assignable to parameter of

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nodes, syntax-highlighting

What should I do in the function `createField` in order to remove this syntax error highlighting?

```
const createField = (
    dataType,
    options = {
        required: false,
        label: null,
        min: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
        max: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
        email: false,
        match: false
    }
) => {
    return {
        dataType,
        options: {
            ...options,
            label: options.label && options.label.toString() || null,
        },
    };
};
```

[image]

Comment: `const inferToPartial = <T>(o: T) => o as Partial<T>; /*...*/ options = inferToPartial({ required: false, /*...*/ }) /*...*/;`, alternatively you can type out the entire type again, or pull the default into a variable before the function, and use its type to not have to write it again. Also see e.g. [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49569665/typescript-default-parameters-for-objects-passed-into-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a possible solution:

```
interface CreateFieldOptions {
  required?: boolean;
  // you need to change the type here
  label?: unknown;
  min?: number;
  max?: number;
  email?: boolean;
  match?: boolean;
}
const createFieldDefaultOptions: CreateFieldOptions = {
  required: false,
  label: null,
  min: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
  max: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
  email: false,
  match: false
}

const createField = (
    dataType,
    options: CreateFieldOptions = {}
) => {
    return {
        dataType,
        options: {
            ...createFieldDefaultOptions,
            ...options,
            label: options.label && options.label.toString() || null,
        },
    };
};
```

**What are the changes?**

- Add an interface to manage the options type -> `CreateFieldOptions`

  - So it can be reused
- Extract the default options into a separate variable -> `createFieldDefaultOptions`

  - Your intent seems to be to merge the default options with the provided passed options. But that is not possible via the parameter assignment, so it has to be done later (see last bullet point)
- The type of the `options` parameter is now an optional `CreateFieldOptions`
- The returned object with the `options` attribute is extended by the `createFieldDefaultOptions`

  - The order is important! `createFieldDefaultOptions` needs to be first, so that it can be overridden by the provided `options`